# I need to display paintings based on genre in a HTML template

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Im doing a project thats a fine art gallery and have different pages based on each painting genre eg. Impressionism, Surrealism etc

i duplicated the all paintings template and want to modify it so it only displays a chosen genre.

Here is my all_paintings view

```
def all_products(request):
"""a view to show all products including search"""

products = Painting.objects.all()
products = Painting.objects.filter(genre__name='genre')

for p in products:
    print(p)

context = {
    'products': products,
}

return render(request, 'products/paintings.html', context)
```

Id like to know if can add a filter like above to an existing class or make an entirely new class?

and also what do i add to the HTML template so the specific genre paintings will be shown

Comment: Could you clarify regard the filter. You asking about is there a way to select a group of images in the Painting class?

Comment: Thats correct i want to select and display a group of images based purely on the genre

Answer (score 0):

Just for instance:

1. A filter:

```py
class Painting:

    def __init__(images_groups = dict()):
        """The constructor. You may pass a dict ({'genre': [img1, img2, ...]})
         """
        self.objects_dict = images_groups
    
    def get_objects(genre=None):
       """Returns the entire dict with all objects if a specific genre isn't passed
       otherwise the objects correspondent to this genre.
       """
       return self.objects_dict if genre == None else self.objects_dict[genre]
    
    def get_objects_by_filter(genre):
        return self.objects_dict[genre]
```

2. Apropos the question of the HTML-representation:
   Yep, it is possible via frameworks or html-rendering packages like [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/). Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a separate model, Genre, with a slug field, I would set up a separate URL and view to handle genres.

E.g. add the following in urls.py:

```
path('products/<slug:genre_slug>', views.genre, name='genre')
```

And in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def genre(request, genre_slug):

    genre = get_object_or_404(Genre, slug=genre_slug)

    products = Painting.objects.filter(genre=genre)

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'genre': genre
    }
    
    return render(request, 'products/genre.html', context)
```

Then in your template, a starting point would be:

```
<h1>Products in {{ genre.name }} genre</h1>

{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! i didnt have a model but added it now in the products model

class Genre(models.Model):

    genre = (
        'impressionism',
        'expressionism',
        'baroque',
        'surrealism',
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

Comment: Im sure not too sure about this